# how to add an attribute to an XML element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am using the DOM parser. I have to parse the following XML:

```
    <abc>
       <type action="">
          <code>test</code>
          <value>001</value>
       </type>
       <type action="">
          <code>test2</code>
          <value>002</value>
       </type>
    </abc>
```

so, depending on the `value` field under the `type` field, I have to fill in the `action` attribute in the `type` field. I am a bit stumped. I am able to get the value of the `value` field, but I don't know how to go back and add the attribute.

Any help will be appreciated a lot!!!

thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have, otherwise hard to suggest what need to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

To go back, just save a reference to the `type` `Element` before you traverse to its `value` child. (assuming you visited it already).

to change the value, use the [setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

edit:

Alternate method: from the `value` text node, call `getParentNode()` twice (once to get back to the value element & once to get back to the type element), then call `setAttribute()` after you do any necissary casting.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("value");
for (Element element : nodelist) {
Element parent = element.getParentNode()
parent.setAttribute("action", "attrValue");
}
```

Comment: The read/modify/write cycle is described well in articles such as [Parsing, Modifying, and outputting XML Documents with Java](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/445.cfm) and [How to modify XML file in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).